# Why did npm update axios fail to update but npm uninstall then install can?

Tags: npm, axios, package.json, semantic-versioning

I used `"axios": "^0.19.2"`, running `npm i` gave the warning "**npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1.**" so I run `npm update -S axios` to update it. But it failed to update axios. I run `yarn upgrade axios` but it failed too.

I had thought there maybe a module required `0.19.2` so I checked `package-lock.json` and I found the only module in my project that requires axios is `pm2` but it requires `"axios": "^0.21.0"`,

```
"@pm2/js-api": {
  "version": "0.6.7",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@pm2/js-api/-/js-api-0.6.7.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-xxxxxxxx",
  "requires": {
    "async": "^2.6.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "debug": "~4.3.1",
    "eventemitter2": "^6.3.1",
    "ws": "^7.0.0"
  },
```

I have no idea why npm update failed to update axios. I then run `npm uninstall axios`, `npm install -S axios` then `"axios": "^0.27.2"` is installed.

But why ?

--- update ---

To verify whether I can reproduce this issue or not I create a project at https://github.com/qiulang/npm-update-error-demo

It shows that even I only have one dependency `axios`, `npm update axios` still failed to update. BTW I use npm 8.x (try both 8.5 & latest 8.11)

Comment: what is the failure message you received? can you replicate it again?

Comment: @RajaniB I figured out why please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I run `npm update  -S axios --loglevel verbose` with npm 6 I got the result

> npm verb outdated not updating axios because **it's currently at the
> maximum version** that matches its specified semver range

If I run with npm 8 I even got 404 error

> npm verb audit error HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - POST
> https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick

So I had thought could this be npm bug ? Suddenly I realize this was caused by `Caret Ranges` ^ I used because normally `^` means patch and minor updates (most people are familiar with that) but it only means for the **patch updates** for versions 0.X >=0.1.0 as [npm document says](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004)

> Many authors treat a 0.x version as if the x were the major
> "breaking-change" indicator.
>
> Caret ranges are ideal when an author may make breaking changes
> between 0.2.4 and 0.3.0 releases, which is a common practice.
>
> ...
>
> ^0.2.3 := >=0.2.3 <0.3.0

BTW because many answers were given to [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) so the answer about patch only for ^0.x was buried in them.